# Subdomain pointing to Amazon S3 bucket doesn't work in UK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns

There is strange problem 
I have a DNS Zone file with CNAME pointing to

scdn.mobidonia.com -> scdn.mobidonia.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com

This doesn't work in UK. In all other countries it works tested in ( USA, Germany, Netherlands, Macedonia). It was working like 2 days ago.

I tested with
http://www.uk-proxy.co.uk

scdn.mobidonia.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com is accessible in UK
scdn.mobidonia.com is not

I see this problem very strange.

I have other subdomain from other hosting "apps.alarconfilms.com" it points to other bucket in Amazon S3, that points to scdn.mobidonia.com and he also doesn't work.

Really strange.

Answer (score 0):

When redirecting domain to an Amazon S3 bucket, you will need to name the bucket the same as the domain name.

This is because, when S3 receives the redirected traffic, it doesn't know which bucket to use. So, it looks for a bucket with the matching domain name.

Make sure your bucket is called "scdn.mobidonia.com".

(This is different to bucket-level redirection, which can be defined within the bucket configuration in S3.)

Comment: Yes, the bucket name is same as the domain name.

As I said, it was working few days ago. I'm now in Bulgaria. And here doesn't work also :(

In Macedonia works, in UK and Bilgaria it doesn't